# Create a UNION ALL query when the columns are in different order

Tags: sql, t-sql, union-all

I have 600 tables to perform a `UNION ALL` query on. Unfortunately the order of the columns in each table varies, however they will always have the same name - example:

Table 1

```
    Item, Cost, ID, Code, Location
```

Table 2

```
    Cost, Id, Code, Location, Item
```

Table 3

```
    Id, Code, Cost, Item, Location
```

Is there a way to write the Union query so it will match the column names, no matter the order in the original table?

Comment: You have to rearrange the columns so that the data types match. The names of the columns will be derived from the 1st query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, no.  `UNION ALL` goes by position not by names.  However, you can generate the columns:

```
select string_agg(column_name, ', ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ? and
      table_schema = ?;
```

You can then plug the list into your code.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will locate all of the tables with the specified columns in any order. It will then use the list to assemble a query that unions the data from all of the tables with the columns in the same order for each table.

```
declare @Query as NVarChar(max);
-- Quote column names here as needed:
declare @Prefix as NVarChar(64) = N'select Id, Item, Code, Location, Cost from ';
declare @Suffix as NVarChar(64) = NChar( 13 ) + NChar( 10 ) + N'union all' + NChar( 13 ) + NChar( 10 );

with
  TargetTables as (
    -- All of the table which have the specified list of columns, regardless of column order.
    select T.Table_Schema, T.Table_Name
      from Information_Schema.Tables as T inner join
        Information_Schema.Columns as C on C.Table_Schema = T.Table_Schema and C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
    where C.Column_Name in ( 'Id', 'Item', 'Code', 'Location', 'Cost' ) -- Do not quote column names here.
    group by T.Table_Schema, T.Table_Name
    having Count( Distinct C.Column_Name ) = 5
    )
  -- Build the query by inserting   @Prefix   and   @Suffix   around each properly quoted table schema and name.
  select @Query = (
    select @Prefix + QuoteName( Table_Schema ) + '.' + QuoteName( Table_Name ) + @Suffix
      from TargetTables
      order by Table_Schema, Table_Name
      for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' );

-- Clean up the tail end of the query.
select @Query = Stuff( @Query, DataLength( @Query ) / DataLength( N'-' ) - DataLength( @Suffix ) / DataLength( N'-' ) + 1, DataLength( @Suffix ) / DataLength( N'-' ), N';' );

-- Display the resulting query.
--   In SSMS use Results To Text (Ctrl-T) to see the query on multiple lines.
select @Query as Query;

-- Execute the query. NB: The parentheses are required.
execute ( @Query );
```

Depending on your needs you can run this once to get the query and cut'n'paste the resulting statement to some appropriate place, e.g. a stored procedure or view, or you can let it generate the dynamic SQL and execute it.

Additional validation, e.g. excluding system tables, is left to the reader.

Comment: Holy heck ! Thank you so much for this! This is awesome!

Comment: @James2086 - Sure, I should have taken the time to make the input a comma-delimited list of column names, split it, quoted them, reassembled them into the select list for the prefix, joined with the split list to find the tables with those columns, and used the count in the `having` clause, but I was lazy. What do you expect from a pandemic volunteer? Happy that it helped.

Comment: thats ok! I'd prefer a hint than the whole answer, this is a great starting point.